# Trying to resolve a InvalidTokenAuthenticity Issue and discovered NO SESSION is even being passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, parallels, ietester

I'm using IETester to debug running Parallels on a Mac OS.

Everytime I send an AJAX request out I consistantly get a InvalidAuthenticityToken response.

I've covered every possible issue.

Then I threw in a debugger, and compared session[:_csrf_token] to the form_authenticity_token.

On my mac they matched.

But on my IETester/Parallells I get this :

```
(rdb:5664) pp session
{}
```

NO SESSION AT ALL!

QUESTION: IS THIS BECAUSE IETESTER IS A B#@CH? And is it possible that it will work with any other windows operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES IETESTER doesn't store Session data and is completely inadequate for testing your websites.

Comment: @jeff, I am using a virtual machine parallels, but it looks like I have to install/uninstall different versions of IE to test functionality and leave just design aesthetics to IETester.

Comment: I mean full-on virtual machines.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575